# TileEntity cannot save NBT correctly

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

NBT was lost when reloading the map. At first I thought it was because the data was not synchronized to the client, but after debugging breakpoints, I found that the parameter tag of writeToNBT was always empty. Does this mean that writeToNBT did not save NBT at all? I did Is it wrong, my version is 1.12.2

```
public class BlockEntityTest2 extends Block {

    public BlockEntityTest2() {
        super(Material.ROCK, MapColor.LIGHT_BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasTileEntity(IBlockState state) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public TileEntity createTileEntity(World world, IBlockState state) {
        return new MyLavaFurnaceEntity();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBlockActivated(World world, BlockPos pos, IBlockState state, EntityPlayer player, EnumHand hand, EnumFacing facing, float hitX, float hitY, float hitZ) {

        if (!world.isRemote && hand == hand.MAIN_HAND) {
            MyLavaFurnaceEntity tile = (MyLavaFurnaceEntity) world.getTileEntity(pos);
            player.sendStatusMessage(new TextComponentString("Fuel: " + tile.getFuel()), true);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public class MyLavaFurnaceEntity extends TileEntity {

        public int fuel;

        public int getFuel() {
            fuel++;
            markDirty();
            return fuel;
        }

        @Override
        public void readFromNBT(NBTTagCompound tag) {
            super.readFromNBT(tag);
            //world_editor.logger.info("readFromNBT fuel:"+fuel);
            //boolean remote = world.isRemote;

            fuel = tag.getInteger("fuel");
        }

        @Override
        public NBTTagCompound writeToNBT(NBTTagCompound tag) {

            tag.setInteger("fuel", fuel);

            return super.writeToNBT(tag);
        }


    }
}
```